# Convert MS Access Transform Query with Count into SQL Server PIVOT

Tags: ms-access

TRANSFORM Count(dbo_t_MARKETO_Comined_Analytics.[Email Address]) AS [CountOfEmail Address]
SELECT dbo_t_MARKETO_Comined_Analytics.[Email Address]
FROM dbo_t_MARKETO_Comined_Analytics
GROUP BY dbo_t_MARKETO_Comined_Analytics.[Email Address]
PIVOT dbo_t_MARKETO_Comined_Analytics.Source;

Comment: What's wrong with the query as is?

Comment: It does not run in SQL Server ! Thanks, Wayne

Comment: Review https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample/, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server